# How can I cancel task from within Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

```
    new Thread(() -> {
        while(true) {
            execute();
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
            if(hasLoopedEnough)
                return;
        }
    }).start();
```

Suppose I wanted to rewrite this using ScheduledExecutorService. In above code it's only the loop/thread itself that knows when to stop the process.
But if I use

```
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 0, 10, SECONDS);
```

How can I cancel this task from within the runnable itself?

**Edit to elaborate the issue with rewriting into ExecutorService:**

Here is an example of how I have been advised to use ScheduledExecutorService instead of manual threads and Thread.sleep:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ScheduledFuture<?> fut = null;

Runnable task = () -> {
    execute();
    //don't need to impose delay - it's handled by scheduler
    if(hasLoopedEnough) {
        //I want to stop any and all calls to execute() before task has been scheduled again.
        //one answer suggested fut.cancel(true) but I have concerns that this is leaking an uninitialized variable.
    }
};

fut = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //this correctly achieves the same effect of looping and imposing 10 seconds delay
fut.cancel() //this does NOT correctly achieve the effect of stopping the loop because only the thread actually running execute() should know when to stop
```

The question then is how can I achieve, using `scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay`, the same thing as I do in the first code snippet in this post where I start a single thread to loop and eventually reach an exit condition?

Comment: What do you want exactly? To stop the executor itself?

Comment: @pringi No, I don't want to stop the executor. The same task will be started up again when needed at a later point (with the same executor). I just want to stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The method "scheduleWithFixedDelay" returns a ScheduledFuture<?> object. keep a reference to this object and use its "cancel" method.
see documentation here:
[cancel method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean))

this doesnt guarantee the task will be cancelled immediately, and it might also try to interrupt the thread (and cause it to throw an InterruptedException inside the thread) depending on the boolean flag you specify in the cancel method.

Comment: But won't the Runnable potentially reference the ScheduledFuture before it's properly instantiated? Can I ask for a code example

Comment: the Runnable has no knowledge of the Future<?> object. the Future object is what the executor uses to relay information back to whoever submitted the task.

Comment: If your answer did not imply that the Runnable should reference the Future<?> object to cancel itself then I do not understand what you are proposing.

Answer (score 0):

We can cancel a task running on a dedicated Thread by invoking Thread.interrupt.This approach is applicable only if the application owns the thread, if the application is using a thread pool, the ExecutorService implementation not the application owns the threads. Thus we mustn't directly interrupt the worker threads in a pool.

```
    public class CancelTaskWithInterruption {

    public void startAndCancel() throws InterruptedException {
        final Runnable task = () -> {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                // Do some work.
            }
            System.out.println("Stopping...");
        };
        final Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2); // Wait for some time
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are interrupting the task from another thread, however. This is exactly what I want to avoid doing.